# Javascript - Stingify : formatting numbers for Google charts

Tags: json, google-visualization, string-formatting

I am trying to understand why the 2 below code do not produce the same output. All my data in my DataTable are well formatted: 11254 shows as 11,254.

```
view.setColumns([1, {
    calc: "stringify",
    sourceColumn: 1,
    type: "string",
    role: "annotation"
}]);
```

The above creates 2 column. One is the original column 1 from the dataTable. The second one is a String for the Annotation of my chart. All numbers end up being well formatted: 11,254.

```
view.setColumns([1,{
    role: "annotation",
    type: "string",
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        if dt.getValue(row, 1) == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            return JSON.stringify(dt.getValue(row, 1));
        }
    }
}]);
```

In this case the numbers converted to String are not formatted anymore: 11254 instead of 11,254. Are those 2 stringify function not the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "stringify" function is not documented, but based on observation, it returns the formatted value of a cell.  Your second function is returning a string based on the value, not the formatted value, of the cell.  If you want to make them equivalent, you need to do this:

```
view.setColumns([1,{
    role: "annotation",
    type: "string",
    calc: function (dt, row) {
        if dt.getValue(row, 1) == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        else {
            return JSON.stringify(dt.getFormattedValue(row, 1));
        }
    }
}]);
```